# Compare dates in xpath 1.0

Tags: xpath

How to compare the dates in xpath 1.0 which is in format like 26 oct 2012. In that I want to

select only those nodes whose date > '26 oct 2012' . and date in nodes are in format 2 Nov

2012, oct 2012.

Is it possible in xpath 1.0. Please give me any solution.

Answer (score 0):

On .NET you could write your own extension XPath function that would know how to handle these. The easiest way to compare dates in XPath 1.0 is to convert them to YYYMMDD format and compare as numbers (or strings). Again, I don't have any context on how you use your XPath but if this was in Xslt it would be doable.

Comment: I am using jaxen 1.1.4 and is it possible to use this function op:date-greater-than($arg1 as xs:date, $arg2 as xs:date) as xs:boolean

Comment: What changes are needed if I want to use xpath 2.0 ?